# What is this symbol?

Tags: notation

I am reading "Sets, Numbers and Topology" by Masahiko Saito.
And the following symbol is used to denote the set of equivalence classes in the book.

What is this symbol?
$J$?
$T$?

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like $\mathcal{F}$ (mathcal{F}) to me.

Comment: It is an uppercase F letter, in a fancy font. You can't miss it thanks to the small horizontal bar.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Thank you very much.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma

Comment: First off, there is a dedicated TeX.stackexchange site. This is probably better to ask there. Second, it looks like it belongs to the mathpzc font, but I can't make it here to try it out and/or demonstrate.

Comment: Can you show more context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a calligraphic F. The closest looking I know for use with LaTeX is the `dutchcal` font (available on CTAN):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I belive it represents the Fourier transform. I use it frequently and am always fighting font types and editors to try to get it to render nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is based on a [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) F, like  or $\mathfrak{F}$

In MathJax, you can use `\mathfrak{F}`

Comment: It is more rounded than a Fraktur.

Comment: $\mathscr{F}$, or $\mathcal{F}$, or $\mathit{F}$, or one of the possibilities given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).